# Unable to access server while file upload in progress (jquery fileupload, nginx, nodejs, busboy)

Tags: node.js, nginx, file-upload, busboy

I'm dealing with a strange issue where while uploading a file to the server, you're not able to make any other POST requests. The error is thrown by nginx, indicating the following (nginx error log)

```
10855 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client
```

My assumption is that since the upload makes use of a read stream, the nodejs app sort of 'locks' into a read stream state where it won't allow any other POST requests that would interfere with the read stream. However, that's just a wild guess.

Any thoughts?

Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    server_name myserver.com;

    location / {
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Server code

```
module.exports.upload = function(req, res) {

  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

    pipetoS3(file, guid + '_' + filename, mimetype, hash, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("success!");
      }
    });
  });
}

const pipetoS3 = function(readStream, key, mimetype, hash, callback) {
  //var compress = zlib.createGzip();
  var upload = s3Stream.upload({
    Bucket: "mybucket",
    Key: hash + '/' + key,
    ACL: "public-read",
    ContentType: mimetype
  });

  // Optional configuration 
  upload.maxPartSize(20971520); // 20 MB 
  upload.concurrentParts(5);

  // Handle errors. 
  upload.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
    console.log('success!');
  });

  // Pipe the incoming filestream through compression, and up to S3. 
  //readStream.pipe(compress).pipe(upload);
  readStream.pipe(upload);
}
```